# How can I close a bootstrap modal after someone clicks a facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've got a facebook modal pop-up that I have a facebook like/share button pasted in.

The button works fine. The modal close button works fine.  I'm wondering if there's a way for me to have the modal close AFTER both the like and share button have been clicked using PHP. Thoughts? Thanks!

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-example" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-example" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">LIKE AND SHARE TO WIN</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <h4>Like us on facebook, share our page, and automatically get entered to win!</h4>
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/page" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the [Facebook javascript api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) to detect when a user clicks the like button.

Comment: How can that be done? Is there a specific thing I need to edit?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually close a modal by calling `$('modalname').modal('hide');` in your JavaScript, or calling to something that in turn calls to the hide method.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Comment: I have done that.  I guess my question should have been more specific - when you click on the facebook like button, it then brings up dropdown that has a close button on it.  I'd like to make the modal button to change to reflect that they have clicked and liked. Does this make sense? Is this possible even?

Comment: As Jerodev has indicated above, you can use the Facebook API to figure out if/when the user has clicked both buttons, and make your calls from there. Your question title is basically asking, "How can I close a modal after something has been done?" That's why I answered the way I did.